# Post method not working with IIS rewrite rule

Tags: php, iis, url-rewriting

I am having issue after I have added the rewrite rule in IIS. I am using PHP as base code, but when I am posting the data the post is not working.

This is the rule that I have added:

```
<rule name="Hide .php ext">
        <match url="^(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
        <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php" matchType="IsFile" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.php" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Redirecting .php ext" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^(.*).php" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*).php"  />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: I think you should avoid using these rules for post data. What about add <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="POST" negate="true" /> to your rule to bypass post method?

Comment: I tried this one but it didnt work I tried to add 
<add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="POST" negate="true" />
<add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="GET" negate="true" />
these two lines and it went to 404 when I removed GET method it started working but again have the same issue with post method

Comment: If so, please enbale failed request tracing. We need raw data and detailed error message to troubleshooting this issue.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: Is their a way I can enable the GET option as well. While i am trying to add GET it just breaks. I think main issue is with GET

Comment: I have enabled FRT as well but its not showing anything

Comment: Have you enabled edit site tracing->Enable in failed request tracing panel?

Comment: It is already enabled